# I want to sum value from dict

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following output:

```
  "vmoff2": [
        {
            "sec_sys": "CONT1",
            "vm_na": {
                "vm1": "Running",
                "vm2": "Running",
                "vm3": "Not Activated",
                "vm4": "Not Activated",
                "vm5": "Running",
                "vm6": "Not Activated"
            }
        },
        {
            "sec_sys": "CONT2",
            "vm_na": {
                "vm1": "Not Activated",
                "vm2": "Not Activated",
                "vm3": "Running",
                "vm4": "Running",
                "vm5": "Not Activated",
                "vm6": "Running"
            }
        }
    ]
---------------
    "vmprof2": [
        {
            "proc": {
                "vm1": "0.5",
                "vm2": "0.7",
                "vm3": "1.0",
                "vm4": "0.5",
                "vm5": "0.5",
                "vm6": "0.5"
            },
            "sec_sys": "CONT1"
        },
        {
            "proc": {
                "vm1": "1.0",
                "vm2": "0.7",
                "vm3": "1.0",
                "vm4": "0.7",
                "vm5": "0.5",
                "vm6": "0.7"
            },
            "sec_sys": "CONT2"
        }
    ]
```

And want to sum the proc of the not activated VM, comparing with wmoff2, the out expected will be:

```
proc_steal:
     
- server: CONT1
  proc: 1.7
- server: CONT2
  proc: 2.4
```

I tried the following:

```
  - name: create proc_steal list
      set_fact:
        proc_steal: >-
          {{ proc_steal | default([])
          + [{
              'sec_sys': item.sec_sys,
              'proc': vmprof2
                | selectattr('sec_sys', '==', item.sec_sys)
                | selectattr('proc', '==', item.vm_na)
                | sum(attribute='value')
                | float
            }]
          }}
      loop: "{{ vmoff2 }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.sec_sys }}"
```

but i get:

```
    "proc_steal": [
        {
            "proc": 0.0,
            "sec_sys": "CONT1"
        },
        {
            "proc": 0.0,
            "sec_sys": "CONT2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is not making the sum, maybe because is not float, but when i tried to put float i got an error "float object is not iterable", so how can i sum that values?

Answer (score 1):

For example, to sum all VM

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        proc_steal: "{{ dict(_serv|zip(_proc)) }}"
      vars:
        _serv: "{{ vmprof2|json_query('[].sec_sys') }}"
        _proc: "{{ vmprof2|json_query('[].proc.*')|
                           map('map', 'float')|
                           map('sum')|
                           map('round', 2)|list }}"
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  proc_steal:
    CONT1: 3.7
    CONT2: 4.6
```

You can convert it to a list if you want to

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        proc_steal: "{{ dict(_serv|zip(_proc))|
                        dict2items(key_name='server', value_name='proc') }}"
      vars:
        _serv: "{{ vmprof2|json_query('[].sec_sys') }}"
        _proc: "{{ vmprof2|json_query('[].proc.*')|
                           map('map', 'float')|
                           map('sum')|
                           map('round', 2)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  proc_steal:
  - proc: 3.7
    server: CONT1
  - proc: 4.6
    server: CONT2
```

---

To sum the *Not Activated* VM only, create a dictionary first

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vm_na: "{{ dict(_serv|zip(_vmna)) }}"
      vars:
        _serv: "{{ vmoff2|json_query('[].sec_sys') }}"
        _vmna: "{{ vmoff2|json_query('[].vm_na')|
                          map('dict2items')|
                          map('selectattr', 'value', 'eq', 'Not Activated')|
                          map('map', attribute='key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  vm_na:
    CONT1:
    - vm3
    - vm4
    - vm6
    CONT2:
    - vm1
    - vm2
    - vm5
```

Then use it to select the machines

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        proc_steal: "{{ proc_steal|d({})|combine({item.sec_sys: _proc|float}) }}"
      loop: "{{ vmprof2 }}"
      vars:
        _proc: "{{ vm_na[item.sec_sys]|map('extract', item.proc)|
                   map('float')|
                   sum|
                   round(2) }}"
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  proc_steal:
    CONT1: 2.0
    CONT2: 2.2
```

, or

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        proc_steal: "{{ proc_steal|d([]) + [{'server': item.sec_sys,
                                             'proc': _proc|float}] }}"
      loop: "{{ vmprof2 }}"
      vars:
        _proc: "{{ vm_na[item.sec_sys]|map('extract', item.proc)|
                   map('float')|
                   sum|
                   round(2) }}"
```

gives the list if you want to

```yaml
  proc_steal:
  - proc: 2.0
    server: CONT1
  - proc: 2.2
    server: CONT2
```

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, exist a way without using json_query?

Comment: Sure. What's preventing you from trying? If you have a problem open [mre].

Comment: I dont have community.general installed. I cant install it.

Comment: The collections are installed by default. What do you need *community.general* for?

Comment: Im getting the following error: ```{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ vmoff[item.sec_sys] | map('extract', item.proc) | map('float') | sum | round(2) }}: 'list object' has no attribute 'CONT1'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/val2.yml': line 87, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: create proc_steal list\n      ^ here\n"}```